# Changing A Lists row color based on a number

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering

So I have a calculated field in my List view that gives the number of days from the contract end date - current date. I wrote the following script to change the color of the row if less then 90 or greater then 90 days.

I cannot seem to get it to work, pretty much the first SharePoint Script I have written. Could anyone point out what is wrong?

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [
    HighlightRowOverride
];

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function HighlightRowOverride(inCtx) {


    for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {
        var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row[i];

        var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);
        var row = document.getElementId(idd);

        if (listItem.[Contractdaysleft] > 90) {

            row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //yellow

        }

        if (listItem.[Contractdaysleft] < 90) {

                    row.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //red

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: How do you add additional information? Tried to but seems there are major restrictions.

Comment: You can edit your own post and get more privileges if you gain more points.

Answer (score 3):

First answering your question:

```
listItem.[Contractdaysleft]
```

Should be written as:

```
listItem.Contractdaysleft

//which is the same as:

listItem["Contractdaysleft"]
```

## Writing less JavaScript using [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io)

I took the liberty of making your **Contracts and End Date** question use-case
into an [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) example

With this *Open-Source* CSR support library it can be done in one statement.

**And you do not need any other Today calculations in your list**

If you have a column "ContractEndDate" (*or any DateTime column*), you declare:

```
      "ContractEndDate":{
        View : iCSR.DueDate({
          ranges:'red,89,white,90,yellow',
          rowcolor:true,
        })
      }
```

To produce:

[image]

(*blurred image caused by imgur host jpg compression*)

**Note: your code did not code the 90 days date either**

**No need for OnPostRender or anything else**

## All CSR code required

Ofcourse you need to load the [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) library BEFORE the CSR code executes.

So the **complete CSR file** (csr_contracts.js) will be:

```
function executeCSR() {//function gets called AFTER the iCSR library is loaded
  var csrfile="~siteCollection/Style Library/csr_contracts.js";//name of this csr file
  function init(){
    var overrides={
      Templates: {
        Fields: {
          "ContractEndDate":{//date column with the contract end date
            View : iCSR.DueDate({
              ranges:'red,89,white,90,yellow',
              rowcolor:1,
            })
          }
        }//Fields
      }//Templates
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
  };//init
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens(csrfile), init);
  init();// MDS safe
};//executeCSR
//Using the public demo version, download the library to your own server
SP.SOD.registerSod("iCSR", 'https://365csi.nl/iCSR/iCSR.js');//register external library
SP.SOD.executeFunc("iCSR", null, executeCSR );//load the iCSR library
if (typeof iCSR !== 'undefined') executeCSR();//line only required so Cisar does live edits
```

## [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) can do better

Text color contrast is an issue, and you probably want some more highligting of important info:

Change the View definition to:

```
      "ContractEndDate":{//date column with the contract end date
        View : iCSR.DueDate({
          ranges:     "coral/red,-1,lightcoral,0,khaki/red,89,lightgreen,90,yellowgreen",
          rowcolor:   true,
          red:        "style=color:[msRed]",
          labelNodate:"<i [red]>No Contract Enddate!</i>",
          labelToday: "<b [red]>Today</b>",
        })
```

And you get:

[image]

#### I do hope that code needs no explanation...

[iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) is the result of making my own CSR development as easy as 1,2,3

(*and a huge ambition to proof jQuery development is something of the past*)

[image]

#### [iCSR.js](http://iCSR.github.io) is [open source on GitHub](http://iCSR.github.io)

## Editing CSR files

Please use the [Cisar Chrome Browser extension](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar) by Andrei Markeev

**"*It is the best thing since sliced bread*"** -- Danny Engelman

[image]

iCSRjs

Comment: iCSR looks very cool. Great work :)

Comment: JSLink deployment is a big issue when you do more CSR development; I spent 2 weeks creating https://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html .. makes JSLinking a breeze.. love it almost as much as Andrei Markeevs [Cisar](http://e2.nl/cisar)

Answer (score 0):

Do you think its the typo in the code...'iid' and 'idd'?

If that's not it, check the dev tools to see if you see any errors in the console.
Then write the values of 'iid' and 'row' to console using `console.log(iid)` and `console.log(row)`. Check if any of those values are undefined.

Do the same inside the if conditions too.
Let me know at what point you are having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

listItem.[Contractdaysleft] is this correct? i think it should be listItem[Contractdaysleft] without dot.

Comment: OK so I made the typo changes and no effect. So I decided to comment out the if statements and just try to at least turn the row yellow and that didn't even work.

Comment: (function () {
 var overrideCtx = {};
 overrideCtx.Templates = {};
 overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [
 HighlightRowOverride
];

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function HighlightRowOverride(inCtx) {
 for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {
  var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row[i];
  var idd = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);
  var row = document.getElementId(idd);
  row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 
 }

inCtx.skipNextAnimation = true;
}

Comment: did you debug the script? may be code in the loop is not executing.

Comment: OK so now I have made it as simple as possible and a few corrections and still cannot get it to even turn a row yellow.

Comment: (function () {
 var overrideCtx = {};
 overrideCtx.Templates = {};
 overrideCtx.Templates.fields = {'Contractdaysleft': { 'View' : HighlightRowOverride }};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function HighlightRowOverride(inCtx) {
 for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {
  var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row[i];
  var idd = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);
  var row = document.getElementId(idd);
                row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //yellow
}

Comment: IS there something special you have to do to get your list view to use it. I have given it the path in the webpart.

Comment: path is fine, first step of writing a script is to add some alerts in the script to make sure it is being executed.

Comment: Yeah I tried alerts none fired I even put them before thwe first call.

Comment: where did you deploy this script? if a file in master page, JavaScript display template? how did you reference this script in list? did you try setting JSLink property of list view web part?

Comment: if ``Contractdaysleft`` is the FieldName you need to change ``.[Contractdaysleft]`` to: ``.Contractdaysleft`` . In your current code ``Contractdaysleft`` is a variable and probably returns `undefined` now