# Showing Due days in a red colomn based upon the real date of this day and a due column date

Tags: sharepoint-server, date-time, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm trying to figure out, how i could show a list with having real overdue date's in days based upon the current day. (maybe a client side rendering?).

The problem is calculated column can not make use of [`Today`] and SharePoint 2013 (on prem) doesn't recalculate [`Today`] if you use it somewhere, for SharePoint [`Today`] is a meme to the day an entry was made, and isn't recalculated every day.

I tried using a script ( [from here](http://praktischsharepoint.blogspot.nl/2013/03/aanpassen-van-sharepoint-lijst.html) ), adjusted it with image link references in our own environment. But in the end, I noticed it couldn't work in SP2013, as well the list themselves are a result of scripts(it seams), if I check the HTML code of a page, I cannot find my date items back, and that script was supposed to find a specific html pattern and change it.

Ideally I'd like to see in red text how many days I am past a due date
But ehm how to get there?

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible to do with Client Side Rendering.  One way to do it would be to add a column to the list called "Days Overdue", and then use a list view override for that field to do the calculations and display your red text message.  However, then you have added a column to your list that you are not actually using to store any data.

As it turns out though, you don't even need to add a column to the list, we can use the CSR framework to insert a fake column to display the "XX days overdue" message in the list view.

```
var DEC = DEC || {};

DEC.DaysOverdueField = (function () {

    function addTemporaryField(ctx) {
        // make sure we haven't added the field already,
        // in case OnPreRender fires twice
        if (ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (fld) {
            return fld.Name == 'DaysOverdueField';
        }).length == 0) {

            // create the field schema object to insert
            var daysOverdueFieldObj = {
                AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
                DisplayName: 'Days Overdue',
                RealFieldName: 'DaysOverdueField',
                Name: 'DaysOverdueField',
                FieldType: 'Text',
                Type: 'Text',
                Filterable: 'FALSE',
                Sortable: 'FALSE',
                ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
            };

            // find the index of the field to insert next to,
            // based on that field's DISPLAY name.
            // in this case i am assuming you want to show the "XX days overdue"
            // message directly next to your due date field,
            // but really you can use this to insert the fake column
            // next to any field you want.
            var insertIdx = ctx.ListSchema.Field.map(function (fld) {
                return fld.DisplayName;
            }).indexOf('Your Due Date Field');

            // if you want to insert *before* the due date field do not add anything
            // but, if you want to insert *after* the due date field, add 1
            insertIdx++;

            // insert your fake field schema object into the list schema
            ctx.ListSchema.Field.splice(insertIdx, 0, daysOverdueFieldObj);
        }
    }

    function calculateOverdueDays(ctx) {
        // get the index of the "Days Overdue" column in the table
        // so we know where to insert the ovedue days message
        var colIndex = 0;
        var headers = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable th');
        var len = headers.length;
        for (var idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
            if (headers[idx].innerHTML.indexOf('Days Overdue') != -1) {
                colIndex = idx;
            }
        };

        // go through the rows and display an overdue message if it is overdue
        ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function (listItem) {
            // get the due date
            // NOTE: this is based on your due date field's INTERNAL name
            var duedate = new Date(listItem.YourDueDateField);

            // use the built in GetDaysAfterToday function to calculate 
            // how many days overdue an item is.  if it is truly overdue, 
            // this function will return a negative number.
            var overdueDays = GetDaysAfterToday(duedate);
            if (overdueDays < 0) {

                // change the negative to a positive
                overdueDays = Math.abs(overdueDays);

                // find the row in the table that corresponds to this list item
                var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
                var row = document.getElementById(iid);

                // insert the overdue message in the <td> element in
                // our temporary "Days Overdue" column
                row.children[colIndex].innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">' + overdueDays + ' days overdue</span>';
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        render: function () {
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
                OnPreRender: addTemporaryField,
                OnPostRender: calculateOverdueDays
            });
        }
    }
})();

RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~site/SiteAssets/Scripts/ShowDaysOverdue.js"), DEC.DaysOverdueField.render);
DEC.DaysOverdueField.render();
```

If you save this script in a file called `ShowDaysOverdue.js`, upload it somewhere on your SharePoint site (make sure you edit the path in the second to last line of the script to reflect the place where you plan to upload the file to), you can then edit the list view web part and link to the script using the view's JSLink property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact code but you can achieve using JSLink functionality by adding script in List view and do the calculations. 
You need to refer this post for doing it : [JSLink reference](http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/creating-a-simple-kpi-column-in-sharepoint-2013-list-views-using-js-link/)

Answer (score 0):

#### How to do it with a Calculated Column:

- https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How

SO answers you should have found:

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)
- [Can anyone color code a column with an if statement?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145693/can-anyone-color-code-a-column-with-an-if-statement/145702#145702)

#### With CSR (+ iCSR.js library from [iCSR.GitHub.io](http://iCSR.GitHub.io)

- [Changing A Lists row color based on a number](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/changing-a-lists-row-color-based-on-a-number/169737#169737)
- [Conditional Formatting Based on Number Range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178358/conditional-formatting-based-on-number-range/178408#178408)